# Proving $\mathbb{R} \cong 2^{\mathbb{N}}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-explanation

I know how to prove that for any set $A$, $\mathcal{P}(A) = 2^A$, where $2^A$ is the collection of sets $A \to \{0,1\}$. I'm not sure if this is particularly helpful in proving that $\mathbb{R} \cong 2^{\mathbb{N}}$, where $2^{\mathbb{N}}$ is the set of functions $\mathbb{N} \to \{0,1\}$. It's possible to approach the proof in terms of decimal or binary expansions, but I haven't been able to sort out the nuances of uniqueness. Shroder-Bernstein seems easier, as it's easier in principle to write two injections than a single bijection, but I'm still struggling with this. I could try to send, for example, a real number $r$ to its binary expansion, but that isn't a well-defined map to $2^{\mathbb{N}}$ unless I "choose a unique binary expansion," which I do not know how to do. I'm not sure how to approach an injection in the opposite direction.

I would appreciate any help. I'll update this post with an updated attempt.

Comment: I think the Continuum Hypothesis needs to be mentioned here but I am ill-equipped to do so meaningfully.

Comment: The set of "non-terminating binary expansions" can give you a well-defined injection $(0,1) \to 2^\mathbb{N}$

Comment: @Shaun I'm similarly ill-equipped, but I don't see how CH matters at all here.  It would be just an "interesting unrelated factoid" in this context.

Comment: This is very helpful. I didn't realize the non-terminating binary expansions were unique, but I'll figure out more on how to prove that. Bijecting $(0,1)$ to $\mathbb{R}$ then gives an injection $\mathbb{R} \to 2^{\mathbb{N}}$. Do you have any tips for the opposite direction?

Comment: The other direction is easier, because you don't have to worry about whether the map is well-defined.  You can just use any base $b \geq 3$ expansion of the real numbers whose digits are determined by the sequence in $2^\mathbb{N}$. (you could use base $2$, but you have to be a little more careful to make it injective) ... Extra credit: Define your function using base $b=3$ to find an explicit bijection between $2^\mathbb{N}$ and the Cantor set $C \subset [0,1]$.

Comment: I will think on this more and try to produce an updated attempt in the first post. Would you mind looking at it after? Thank you again for all your help.

Answer (score 2):

One approach could be to first prove that the open interval $(0,1) \cong 2^\mathbb{N}$ and then $\mathbb{R} \cong (0,1)$.  For every decimal expansion in $(0,1)$, we can associate a unique map $\mathbb{N}\to \{0,1\}$ by sending the $n$th place in the decimal to the binary expansion of the digit.  This can then be precomposed with $\arctan$ with a few modifications.